# Как организовать выделение сделанных изменений (закрашивание ячеек) в Google таблицах?

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet

Задача сосотоит в том, чтобы закрашивать ячейку, в которой произошли изменения.

В обычном Excel все работает с VBA кодом:

```
    Option Explicit
Dim vValue
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target <> vValue Then Target.Interior.Color = vbRed
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count = 1 Then vValue = Target
End Sub
```

Попробовал перенести в google таблицу вот так (что то не правильно!):

```
function Option (Explicit){
var vValue;
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range);
if(Target.Count > 1 ){
Exit Sub;
}
if(Target != vValue ){
Target.Interior.Color = Red;
}
}
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range);
if(Target.Count == 1 ){
vValue = Target;
}
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста как поправить?
Можно ли интегрировать в google таблицы возможности обычного excel?

1. Ссылка на тестовую таблицу google - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HJKrhe-N6MzP0Kq-2faAK_tTAYC2khWdxrneV2gaQp4/edit?usp=sharing
2. Рабочий вариант в Excel - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yT50byq78rT-9BbdzuCQ3eoQSwWPgF6C/view?usp=sharing

Comment: VBA - один язык программирования, а Google Apps Script - совершенно другой. Вот можете почитать про [триггеры](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) и про [Spreadsheet service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/)

Answer (score 0):

Ответ найден (еще добавил примечание с датой изменения)

```
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range;
// Добавим примечание
range.setNote('Дата изменения: ' +(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd.MM.yyyy")));

//Закрасим ячейку
range.setBackground("red");
}
```